# Vlookup issue with flash fill

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having the following issue. When I do a vlookup and flash fill my formula it copies the correct cell references but the value it is showing is the same for the entire column(the value calculated for the first cell). When I go to an individual entry and click enter at the top it evaluates to the correct expression.

How can I make excel evaluate all of the entries in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got formulas calculations set to manual ?

If so turn them back to automatic, see below image to find the setting.

[image]

Also, you can press F9 to force a workbook to re-calculate if you want to leave calculations set to manual.